# What email server sends a 554 error email that looks like this?

Tags: email, exchange-server, spam

I'm running an email campaign and received sporadic 554 errors that all look like the image below. Does anyone know what email server/platform sends 554s that look like this?

[image: 554 error]

Answer (score 0):

This isn´t server/platform specified as SMTP response code are used for multiple applications. However in your case the email you are sending is clarified as SPAM (as seen in the screenshot). The reasons for that is written in the email directly and they do not like your URL in that mail.

To get more specified information's you might check the header from the email.